# emulate mouse cursor on windows 8.1 rt (metro only)?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, mouse, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I would like to know, if it's possible to activate and control the cursor in windows 8.1 rt, from a metro-app?
My approach is:

```
system.windows.forms.cursor.handle
//or
system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition
```

Would this work, and if yes, do I need to initialize the mouse somehow in the first place?

Comment: `Would this work` why don't you just try and find out?

Comment: because atm there is no windows-tablet around. Also I was wondering, why there are no mouse-emulator-apps for windows rt

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The Windows Runtime doesn't provide an API to control the cursor.

You can't use the Windows Forms API, as it can't be imported in projects for Windows Store apps.